# How to open this fluorescent light fixture?

Tags: light-fixture

I’m stumped. There this fluorescent light fixture in a closet of mine that seems to have burned out or stopped working. I wanted to open it up to change the bulb but I can’t figure out how it opens.

I’ve tried pulling, sliding, gentle prying. It’s on there rock solid. There is a ridged (like a potato chip) plastic covering that seems like it could somehow be removed but I can’t figure it out.

I can’t find any identifying markings, no serial number, no manufacturer, so it’s impossible for me to google what the hell this is.

[image: the fixture]

[image: The ridged covering]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is meant to be opened ? Looks like a cheap one that does not have a replaceable bulb. Try pinching lens inward from the side were it curves over and then lifting up. I suspect you are not meant to figure it out.

Comment: Ha. I am certainly not sure of that. How do I remove it from the ceiling if necessary? It’s wired to the wall though, so I’d assume it should be replaceable? Seems weird to be disposable but wired to the house

Comment: Yes that just occurred to  me as well. I think you pinch the sides in towards each other. Pinch in and down to release from metal housing. I think the key lies in the fact that we have opposable thumbs.

Comment: The bezel  that wraps around 90 degrees,  actually has a little bit of  flex. Touch the bezel along the thin edge and push inward maybe 1/4". That should unlatch it and it will pivot outward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the fixtures like this I have repaired the bezel comes out. Pressing on the bezel down flex in then pull out , did that make sense ? 
There are normally 2 clips evenly spaced from the end, normally on the short side of the bezel or plastic lamp cover a light pressure to flex the plastic towards the fixture push like you are putting it on (not all need this but some won’t release with the removal of tension) then while still pressing pull out.  I hope I explained it better. These fixtures are very common most often in a 24” model but I have seen 48” ones. The lamp is normally a standard T8 or t12 bulb I would guess at A T8 and they do go bad.

If you go to a big box store they will probably have one as these are common but today they may have an led lamp. Ask to look at it and to look at the bulb or what type of bulb you need to purchase.

Comment: Exactly correct, the plastic lens is just sorta snapped in there. Flex it down and pull away and it will come right off.